# Import searchbar component with props.navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to import a searchbar component into my containers but the onSearch function does not work. It returns an error 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate'). What am I missing?

In my container, I have:

```
import SearchBar from '../Components/SearchBar'
```

and inside the render function I have

```
<SearchBar />
```

In SearchBar.js:

```
  onSearch(terms) {
      console.log(terms);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductsGrid', {searchTerms: terms})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          ref='searchText'
          value={this.props.searchTerm}
          onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.onSearch(event.nativeEvent.text)}
          returnKeyType={'search'}
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add {...this.props} inside of  to pass the props.

```
<SearchBar {...this.props} />
```